# challenges using devices and stdin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-console

I am using an embedded ubuntu based processor as a machine vision system. It  communicates over 2 serial ports with an associated flight controller.

My problem was that normal open(), close() calls supporting the vision<->flight controller communications caused stdin calls (fgets(), scanf(), etc) to fail in peculiar ways - the calls thought there was input, but there wasn't, and the returned buffer was garbage.

I originally thought this was due to conflicts between the kernel's default text console and my use of the serial devices. After a circuitous search, I realized this was incorrect - I found a subtle bug that caused the device file descriptor to be set to 0 - same as stdin - under some circumstances.

I found this bug by following up a lead from roamina below. I have left his answer as accepted because he set me on the trail to the real problem.

Comments below do have some useful info for others with concerns about devices, stdin, and the default text console.

thanks

Comment: "_Reading suggests that `stty` sets stdin to the port being configured_" - not in my experience. What should happen is that `stty` configures the line attached to its _stdin_. I've also known systems reset the line characteristics when all file descriptors to that device are closed (effectively negating a naive `stty ... </dev/ttyXX` but I have no way of confirming if that also applies to Linux-based systems.

Comment: roaima's comment regarding stdin being set seem correct to me. I took my interpretation from man stty - but it clearly says something different than my original interpretation. I have edited question to avoid confusion.

Comment: well - the problem is actually very different from the question I asked. I figured it out by taking a look at the link roaima noted. It led me on a path that made me realize that there was actually NO tty issue - the problem was a subtle bug that was resetting the open fd to 0. my bad. thank you roaima for sticking with me.

Comment: For those with similar problems: under almost all circumstance the fd for stdin is 0. open() should return a different fd for a legitimately configured open call. If it doesn't, you either closed fd 0, or have a bug that is incorrectly using 0 as fd.

Comment: Finally, the default console is set int the kernel command line. You can view this typically at /proc/cmdline. Changing it depends on what version of linux you are on, If I knew them all I would list them - if you need to sort it out, search for 'kernel command line' and read the details for your version of linux.

Comment: That sounds like a thorough analysis. You could write up (and accept) your own answer, here, containing all this detail. Do feel free to unaccept mine in favour of yours. I'm pleased to hear you finally cracked it!

Comment: No - you def helped. I'll get my first answer points by fixing someone else's bugs! thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to set the terminal line characteristics and have them stick, try this

```
# Serial line
tty=/dev/ttyS1

# Open the serial port and hold it open
sleep 300 <$tty &
slpid=$!

# Set the characteristics and run the serial port code
stty 19200... <$tty
/run/your/program

# Clean up
kill $slpid 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works of course, but is not my actual problem. The more I think about it, I think the kernel has stolen /dev/ttyS2 for its default text console, and I just have to figure out how to change that. There are no grub files unfortunately. I am going to close the question, and ask a better one, unless you object. seth

Comment: @sneiman the [Ubuntu Serial Console Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto) explains the steps to activate a serial console. It might be worth checking that to see if your embedded system already has it enabled, and if so what steps you can take to disable it.